# Как разделить список на список списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как данный список:

```
list(map(taxonomy.get, lst))
```

разделить на отдельные списки.

Например список: `[1, 129, 123, 64, 124, 121]` вывести как `[1], [129], [123], [64],[ 124], [121]`.

Comment: `[[x] for x in list_]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1, 129, 123, 64, 124, 121]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print([a[i]])
```

Comment: А как сделать короткую запись, или как вывести все значения не в список, а каждое значение отдельно. Должно получиться типа так: '1', '129', '123', '64', '124', '121' ?

Comment: @SANCHOS `print(a[i])`, ничего сложного

Comment: Я имел ввиду вывести такой список вне цикла for

Comment: @SANCHOS Ну добавляйте в стринговую переменную типа `s = "" for...: s += a[i] print s`

Comment: Если я выводу то получиться 1, 129, 123, 64, 124, 121. Вроде так и нужно, но если использовать такой вывод когда я собираю кучу переменых в 1 переменую то получаеться что выводиться так '1, 129, 123, 64, 124, 121' тоесть в кавычках, а мне нужно что бы каждый елемент выводился как отдельные елемент

Comment: @SANCHOS Не совсем понимаю. [Вот так?](https://ideone.com/vauXJL)

Comment: У меня есть список. Мне нужно вывести его как a[0], a[1]... Только длина списка всегда разная и если я будут просто перебирать a[0], a[1] то рано или поздно прийду к индексу которого не существует.

Comment: Если ещё проще я вывожу данные в csv и этот список у меня выводиться в 1 ячейке как список, мне нужно что бы каждый елемент списка был в своей ячейке.

Comment: Ну, чем вам тут цикл не подходит? Цикл идет до `len(a)`, дословно до тех пор, пора переменная цикла не дойдет до конца списка, ну и соответственно `i` это номер ячейки, куда нужно записать значение.

Comment: Так в том и проблема, что я вывожу все значения через строку s как вы писали, то я получаю все равно строку с цыфрвми которые разделены запятой. Например сейчас вывод такой ['вывод переменой', ' вывод другой перемененой', " '129' , '123' , '64' , '124' , '121"'] а нужно сделать ['вывод переменой', ' вывод другой перемененой',  '1' , '129' , '123' , '64' , '124' , '121']

Comment: @SANCHOS Сама строка кавычек **не содержит**. [Вот весь код.](https://ideone.com/vauXJL)

Comment: А как вывести не кортежем. А просто как отдельные значения.?

Comment: @SANCHOS Для отдельных значений вам придется создавать переменные для каждого элемента списка. Разве кортеж не легче?

Comment: А возможно с помощью регулярного выражения вытянуть только значения, срезая скобки кортежа?

Comment: @SANCHOS `str(a)` дает вам весь кортеж, переведенный в строку. Удаляете первый и последний символ, и все.

Comment: Если вывести в отдельную переменную с другими переменными получаться что добавляются кавычки, как от них избавиться? https://ideone.com/nyBF0C

Comment: @SANCHOS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом более универсально это можно сделать

```
l = [1, 129, 123, 64, 124, 121]
chunk_size = 1 # кол-во элементов в одном внутреннем списке
new_list = [l[x:x+chunk_size] for x in range(0, len(l), chunk_size)]
```